# I am looking for a regex to pick up all the trailing 0s after decimal from any number along with the decimal

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

Looking to pick up all those 0s which doesn't add any value to a number:

- `1.000` should give `.000`
- `0.000` should give `.000`
- `0.0080` should give me `0`
- however `10` should remain `10`, only after the decimals I want

I tried couple of regex but they are not working correctly, please if anyone can support, would be really appreciated, thanks in advance.

Tried

```
(\.*?)(0+)$
```

but this is picking up 0s which are actually valuable like in `10` or `100` etc.

Comment: Why don't you just convert the input to a number, convert that back to a string, then get the difference between them. That will be the insignificant trailing 0's.

Comment: I think that would give me a 0 in the case if its a number without a decimal like 10, which I don't want, also converting back and forth won't help as I am dealing with millions of records in SQL, I just need to identify those 0s which are not adding any value

Comment: Why do you think that? Converting it to a number will return 10, converting that back to a string will return 10, there won't be any difference.

Comment: Why are you storing numbers as strings in SQL, instead of FLOAT or DECIMAL datatype?

Comment: using the data coming through some external vendors, don't know why they doing that

Comment: @trincot yes its picking up those 0s as well, I tried it, you have a workaround?

Comment: @trincot I have just tried this regex -   (\.*?)(0+)$   at regex101.com overthere too it's picking up the 0s in 100

Comment: So are you looking for a solution with regex101? Then which flavor of regex? For instance, ECMAScript flavour: https://regex101.com/r/06HVMl/1

Comment: in PCRE2, was doing the test

Comment: I just notice there is a point missing in your regex? Did you mean `(\..*?)(0+)$`

Comment: In PCRE `^\d+\.(?:\d*[1-9])?\K0+$` https://regex101.com/r/UYVpKG/1

Comment: Do you only need the zeros? If so, there is no need to capture the first part too. Combination from @trincots correcture and @4th birds [`\K` reset](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#K) e.g. use [`\..*?\K0+$`](https://regex101.com/r/YYwaOT/1)

Comment: @bobblebubble I need the decimal too along with zeros

Comment: @bobblebubble  like if its 1.000 --> .000 0.008090 --> 0  0.000 --> .000  10 --> no output  9900 --> no output

Comment: Use https://regex101.com/r/EzjKE8/2 to remove trailing zeros.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this is doing just the opposite of what is wanted, can this be reversed so that it can pickup from 1.0000 --> .0000 instead of 1

Comment: Yes, just re-group the captures: https://regex101.com/r/EzjKE8/3

Comment: @BhavyaGandhi You can adjust @thefourthbird's regex: [`^\d+\K\.(?:\d*[1-9]\K)?0+$`](https://regex101.com/r/C6qVuC/1) or try [`^\d++\K\.(?:0+|\d*?\K0+)$`](https://regex101.com/r/C6qVuC/3) (due to use of `\K` these will only work in PCRE)

Comment: If you only process such numbers, this part would suffice: [`\.(?:\d*[1-9]\K)?0+$`](https://regex101.com/r/5UPPyl/1)

Comment: thanks everyone for helping out, got it solved